# Send PHP Array To Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

///////UPDATE - I already have jquery library included to my code so if its easier with jquery than javascript let me know please.

OK. There are loads of questions on here that are sending a JavaScript array to php but only 1 which is the same as mine. Unfortunately I didn't understand the answer.

So, at the moment I have an associative array in php. I then used this code,

```
echo json_encode($this->_inputErrors);
```

I don't actualy know why i'm using it, just was mentioned a lot in other examples like this. So that then sends the data to javascript (via ajax) and if i do this code,

```
alert(requestText);
```

I get a long line of text. As I imagine i should.

So how do i then in javascript get the text back to an array?

Or Is there a better way to do this?

Many Thanks For Your Time,

Chris

Comment: `json_encode` converts a PHP object into a JSON one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var o = JSON.parse( requestText );
```

Include this ( https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js ) to support old browsers.

Comment: Thanks For The Reply - I put the code that you wrote and then used alert to see its contents and it gave [object Object]

Comment: That's normal... It's a object... Try `console.log( o );` and open your console, you'll see.

Comment: ok, 2 more questions - is the object an array object? And the link you gave me, Do not all browsers support json?

Comment: No it's not. It's an object. But objects in JavaScript work like associative arrays. And no, not all browser can parse JSON, that's why this function was written :)

Comment: But if you've got jQuery included, just use the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862528/send-php-array-to-javascript/5862577#5862577
jQuery already has a parser in it, there is no need to have 2.

Answer (score 3):

`requestText` is a JSON string.  You need to parse the string into an object.

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert the string to JSON.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(requestText);
```

If your browser doesn't have `JSON`, include this:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: If I include that file will it work for everyone's browsers who view my site?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the return type as `JSON`

or if using jQuery, you can use jQuery's method [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get the JSON object from the url

Comment: OP didn't say they were using jQuery.

Comment: Use this and then just do $.each looping trough all key => values

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean by "set the return type"? I assumed it was to do with `$.ajax` at first but now I don't get it. Do you mean like `content-type` in PHP or something else?

Comment: No use to include jQuery just for that -.-

Comment: Thanks For The Reply - How do I Do That? This is the code i'm using to get the data from php's echo /// requestText = xmlhttp.responseText;

Answer (score 0):

Somedays before, I faced the same problem. Check my solution :)

array.html

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    //This array is where I'll receive the PHParray
    var js_array=new Array();

    $("#btn").click(function(e){
             $.ajax({
                type:    'POST',
                 url:     'vector.php',
                 cache:   false,
                 success: function(data){

                    js_array=data;
                   //I use this "for" to print each array item into a div called "data".
                    for(var i=0;i<js_array.length;i++){
                         $("#data").append("<p>"+js_array[i]+"</p>");
                    }

                 },
                 dataType: 'json'
             });                  
    });                    

});
```

---

vector.php

```
<?php

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

/*As you, I use "json_encode" to serialize the array
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

I hope it can help (:

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to transform that long line of text in Javascript is using eval:

```
alert(eval('(' + requestText + ')'));
```

Comment: eval is evil. Even if you use it the correct way with (). Nothing tells you it's not a script. If you want to do it that way you would rather use JSONP. And btw, always prefer the function constructor to eval because it gives a scope. (yes, I did vote down)

Comment: @xavierm02: Stupid meme is stupid. There's nothing dangerous about `eval`ing your own servers JSON response. And eschewing a quintessential feature of scripting languages for fictional reasons like that is not very clever. (It's also not fashionable to downvote competing answers.)

Comment: If you edit and replace eval by the Function constructor, I take back my downvote :-°

Comment: If you want to use eval, do it correctly as he does: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: But you can avoid it (look at the other files in the repo).

Comment: In fact eval() seems faster ( http://jsperf.com/new-function-vs-eval ) but I'll double-check.

Comment: I was sure that someone will downvote my answer :D But using eval yet remain the simplest way to transform a JSON string to Javascript. Anyway if you think that loading an external library to fall back those browsers that do not support the native JSON.parse or that filtering your own server response is a better solution because you read it somewere fill free to waste your time ;-)

Comment: Filtering server isn't the problem. Read the code written by Douglas. It doesn't only check it is valid JSON. It also adds support for UTF-8 and so on. And as it's becoming a native API, it'll get faster and faster (even though it's slower than eval because it checks if it is valid JSON before executing it).

Comment: Btw, I checked, eval() is much much faster (the crockford guy must have checked that :o ) that new Function() and JSON.parse() is a bit slower than eval(). So the best thing is just to use JSON.parse().

Comment: Alright, but do you agree with me that to add UTF-8 support and so on is often useless if you are working with your own server response? :P

Comment: UTF-8 will become the new standart (and it is already?). I always use UTF-8 and you should too. But we're getting kind of off topic :-° http://annevankesteren.nl/2009/09/utf-8-reasons http://developers.sun.com/dev/gadc/technicalpublications/articles/utf8.html

Comment: I agree that the JSON library by Crockford MUST filter the input, because it was designed to be used in the 100% of the scenarios. But I'm saying that sometimes (maybe the 90% of the times) using just eval is simpler than include an external library, isn't it?

Comment: UTF-8 is nine years old... what does it is becoming a new standard means? Anyway, thank you to worrying about my encoding :D

Comment: Well there are still sites not using it whereas they should.

Comment: Ok, but this isn't a problem of eval, if you set the right encoding of the source data to eval :D